# Dandelion-datatable1.1.1 + thymleaf have error after refresh page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable, dandelion

With the same configuration, use v1.0.1 is ok, when it was replaced by v1.1.0 and 1.1.1-core, it's still ok before refresh the page, but down after refresh(all dropdown menu down, bootstrap-modal become strange and datatable's style changed  e.g.)
My configuration is like this:

```
datatables.properties:
#File containing Dandelion Datatables properties
main.standalone=true
global.css.theme=bootstrap3
global.feature.displayLength=25
global.feature.pagingType=listbox
global.css.class=table table-bordered table-striped dataTable
global.feature.dom = '<"row"<"col-sm-6"l><"col-sm-6"0rf>><"row"<"col-sm-12"t>><"row"<"col-sm-5"i><"col-sm-7"p>>'
global.feature.autoWidth = false
global.feature.processing=false


dandelion.properties:
bundle.includes=dt-functions
asset.minification = true
asset.css.excludes = datatables

dt-functions.json:
{
    "bundle" : "dt-functions",
    "assets": [
        {
            "name": "dt-functions",
            "version": "0.1",
            "type": "js",
            "locations": {
                "classpath": "public/js/dt-functions.js"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "datatable",
            "version": "1.10.7",
            "type": "js",
            "locations": {
                "classpath": "public/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "datatables",
            "version": "1.10.7",
            "type": "css",
            "locations": {
                "classpath": "public/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "bootstrap3-theme-js",
            "version": "1.10.7",
            "type": "js",
            "locations": {
                "classpath": "public/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "bootstrap3-theme-css",
            "version": "1.10.7",
            "type": "css",
            "locations": {
                "classpath": "public/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And because of https: //github.com/dandelion/dandelion/issues/66

I used maven like this:

```
 <properties>
        <dandelion.core.version>1.1.1</dandelion.core.version>
        <dandelion.datatable.version>1.1.0</dandelion.datatable.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${dandelion.datatable.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
                <artifactId>dandelion-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${dandelion.datatable.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
                <artifactId>dandelion-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
        <artifactId>dandelion-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dandelion.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

[before refresh page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5KZu.png)

[after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZefD.png)

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: TypeError: $.AdminLTE is undefined
 

....AdminLTE.options,AdminLTEOptions);var a=$.AdminLTE.options;_init(),$.AdminLTE.l...

 
app.min.js (第 13 行，第 6651 列)
TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
 

function onDatatableInit(){$('.tooltips').tooltip();}

Comment: I testd other versions, actually, start from 1.0.0, once I refersh the page, typeError will appear

Comment: I guess it occurs because of wrong scripts loading order. I had some issues with that and solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218315/dandelion-datatables-cant-load-jquery-ui)
you can try to load all other js libs not in properties but in footer, for example.